# function in p5.js crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to write some code to interpret coding language in a .txt file.   I wrote a function to preformat the  code, but trying to use the function crashes the tab,
here is the function:

```
function preformat(code){ 
  chars = split(code, '');  //splits code into individual characters

  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){  //loops through all characters
    
    let char = chars[i];   // current character
    let nextChar = chars[i + 1]; // next character
    

    if(char === ' ' && nextChar == ' '){   
      chars.splice(i, 1);
      i--;

    } else if(char !== ' ' && nextChar === "+" || "-" || "*" || '/' || "**"){ 
        chars.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    } else if(char === "+" || "-" || "*" || '/' || "**" && nextChar !== " "){
        chars.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    } 
    // add whitespace beside operators
  }
  
  let val = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    val += chars[i];
  }
  // turn back into a string
  
  return val;
}
```

running this `preformat()` function crashes the program, I've done just about everything i can think of.

P.S. I am using the p5.js web editor

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are running into an infinite loop 14 and 16 as these else ifs always evaluate to true and keep inserting new items into the array. Because of that eventually, the page runs out of memory and crashes. The below should work fine:

```js
function preformat(code){ 
  chars = code.split('');  //splits code into individual characters

  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){  //loops through all characters
    
    let char = chars[i];   // current character
    let nextChar = chars[i + 1]; // next character
    

    if(char === ' ' && nextChar == ' '){   
      chars.splice(i, 1);
      i--;

    } else if(char !== ' ' && (nextChar === '+' || nextChar === '-' || nextChar === '*' || nextChar === '/')){ 
        chars.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    } else if((char === '+' || char === '-' || char === '*' || char ==='/') && nextChar !== ' '){
        chars.splice(i, 0, ' ');
    } 
    // add whitespace beside operators
  }
  
  let val = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    val += chars[i];
  }
  // turn back into a string
  
  return val;
}

console.log(preformat("text text"));
```

I've also updated the if checks as some values evaluated to false regardless what (comparing string of length one to string of length two).